# Get the refresh token from the PersistedGrantStore key property in identityserver4

Tags: .net-core, identityserver4

I have already implemented my own `IPersistedGrantStore` called `PostgresPersistedGrantStore` that stores grant in my postgresql database and it works really great.

Now i want to move really forward and i want to get the refresh token from the `key` that is stored in my postgresql table. But from what i read it is not a proper refreshtoken but a hash to protect the refreshtoken. Is there a way to decrypt, read the refresh token from the `key` property, using maybe a fuction from the identityserver api?

I am trying to implement my own impersonation workflow, so it would be easy to login as any user using the latest refresh token that exists persisted in my db

Comment: Have you considered "easy to login as any user" may not be a good idea?  You cant login as someone unless you are that person.   While a client may have been granted access to that persons data and have a refresh token associated with it only that client should be accessing that persons data.

Comment: Guys please don't spam the question impersonation is a standard process for any product when i customer needs support. My app doesnt handle sensitive data. Just asked a question that if you google it will get 15 question on how to impersonate with ids4.

Comment: [girl] definitely not spamming I have been trying to work out how to do this at work.    I am interested in your approach and you thoughts on the security it.   It is not how I intend to do it.

Comment: @GeorgePapadakis did you ever solve this? I have a similar issue, where I have the persistedGrants store and need to display a list of active sessions to a logged in user, and hilight the current one. All I know is the refresh token at that time (from the header) and I need to be able to find which grant in the db it relates to. Even using the same hash method to check against the store would be great, no need to decrypt existing ones, just hash the token in such a way that I can confirm which grant it relates to.

Comment: @MarkMcGookin no i didnt find any solution using persistentgrants.

Answer (score 3):

A long time has passed since the question had been asked, but I think I'm sharing a relevant information.
Here is the method which is implemented at `IdentityServer4.Stores.DefaultGrantStore<T>` and actually creates the `key` for the refresh token.

```
protected virtual string GetHashedKey(string value)
{
    return (value + KeySeparator + GrantType).Sha256();
}
```

Where

- `value` is the actual value of the refresh token,
- `KeySeparator` is a
  constant string field defined at the same class, the
  value is ":",
- `GrantType` is 'refresh_token' in this particular case.

This method is being used while creating/validating the refresh token.
I think this information clearly states that there is no way to get the refresh token value by using the `key`.

Reference:
https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/main/src/IdentityServer4/src/Stores/Default/DefaultGrantStore.cs#L77

Answer (score -2):

Identity Server 4 has a build-in endpoint for this - `<server_url>/Connect/Token`.

You need to send a POST request to this endpoint, with `x-www-form-urlencoded` body type, which contains:

- refresh_token: current refresh_token
- client_id: the client that you are refreshing the token for
- client_secret: the secret of the client
- grant_type: refresh_token

It will give you back a "refreshed" access_token along with a new refresh_token.

The initial refresh_token you should have received once you have logged in. Have in mind - once refresh_token is used (to get a new access_token) it gets *invalidated*. This is why you are receiving a new with every request to the endpoint.

[Here](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/refresh_tokens.html) is some more info about the refresh_token itself.
And [here](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/endpoints/token.html) - about the token endpoint.

Comment: complete irrelevant, i am asking something very specific. How to get the refresh token from the key property in my own IPersistedGrantStore.

Comment: why would you need to get it. The idea of being encrypted is that no one (including admins) cannot get the token

Comment: i am implementing my own impersonation workflow for my app.

Comment: as I said - the initial token will be given to you on login (when receiving the access token, and as long as you are using the proper grant type). If you don't store it at that point, you can't get it again. It is encrypted and protected, and any violation of that, will be a violation of the OAuth concept

Comment: What s violating, the exposed auth api is working as expected, what i am asking is something very internally a workaround for my own, as i said, impersonation mechanism

Comment: Well you cannot just login as any user. This is not how this works. You either login as a specific user, or you either login as a specific client. Of course - you can always fetch the IDS repo, modify it for yourself, to work like you want it and use it. Good luck in certifying this as an OIDC provider

Comment: @m3n7alsnak3 how would you recommend someone implement user delegation / impersonation using Client credentials grant type then?  This is what it sounds like the OP is trying to do, maybe giving him a better way would help.

Comment: @DaImTo - well client credentials is something different. But I don't think that the OP is aiming for that. He just wants to get the latest logged in user, and impersonate as him. I've never taught about impersonation and IDS, but when I hear this word, it always sounds hacky to me. This is why (I guess) there is the client credentials flow - if you want a service, to act as a person - just authenticate it.